# Assetic (Symfony) - Font Awesome doesn't work in dev environment

Tags: symfony, font-awesome, assetic

I'm trying to figure out how to make this icon font work in the dev environment of Symfony. In production environment, everything works fine. I'm using assetic to manage my assets. I downloaded font-awesome with bower. Here's my code:

### config.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ AdminBundle, UserBundle, ShopBundle, SiteBundle ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

### base.html.twig

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        'vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
        'vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'

        filter='?cssrewrite'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

### Snippet from rendered html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Area</title>
    <link href="/stocksolutions/web/app_dev.php/css/00007d5_bootstrap_1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/stocksolutions/web/app_dev.php/css/00007d5_font-awesome.min_2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/stocksolutions/web/app_dev.php/css/b4f457d_part_1_admin_1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/stocksolutions/web/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon">
   </head>
   <body>
    (...)

    <script src="/stocksolutions/web/app_dev.php/js/ddd7e15_jquery.min_1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/stocksolutions/web/app_dev.php/js/ddd7e15_bootstrap.min_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

### font-awesome css-file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
}
```

### Directory Structure

```
- web
--- css
--- fonts
--- js
...
```

Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Can you please show the rendered HTML code to check that the `<link />` tag is present? If you open the URLs to CSS files directly, do you have a 404 error?

Comment: Have you tried `php app/console asset:dump --env=dev`? Seems unusual that the issue would only appear in the dev environment.

Comment: I have dumped the assets and css files are loaded properly.. very strange! I also tried to manually add the files in the fonts folder, but without results. I added some more code snippets in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround works both dev and production mode. I have tested it on Symfony ~2 and ~3 too.

**Summary**

1. Copy the font files into your bundles public folder, in my case:
   `AppBundle/Resources/public/fonts/font-awesome/`
2. Run `bin/console assets:install`, so it will copy this folder under *web/bundles/fonts/font-awesome/* in this case. (*app/console* in older Symfony version)
3. In your CSS file where you define font-face, use this as the path: `../bundles/app/fonts/font-awesome/`
   For example: `../bundles/app/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf`

**Details**

I'm using less css.

**config.yml**

```
assetic:
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    lessphp:
        file: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php"
        apply_to: '\.less$'
        formatter: "compressed"
        preserve_comments: false
```

**snippet from my layout:**

```
{% stylesheets
'@AppBundle/Resources/private/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
'@AppBundle/Resources/private/less/styles.less'
output='css/frontend.css' %}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

**snipets from less files:**

```
//vars.less (this is imported into styles.less)
@fonts_dir: "../bundles/app/fonts/";
@fontAwesomeDir: @fonts_dir + "font-awesome/";
@font-awesome: @fontAwesomeDir + "fontawesome-webfont.ttf";

//font-awesome.less (this is imported into styles.less too)
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('FontAwesome'), url(@font-awesome) format('truetype');
}
```

Hope this helps. If you have questions about this, feel free to ask!